# Recursive wget strip GET parameters

Tags: linux, shell, wget

I am downloading a website I have using wget -r http://example.com but in order for the css files to not be cached, the website adds GET parameters to those files such as styles.css?foobar.

How can I make it download the file and strip ?foobar from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rename the files after `wget` completes.

```
find . -name '*\?*' | while read -r path ; do
    mv "$path" "${path%\?*}"
done
```